# Allowing user input for opening and closing brackets

Tags: string, completing-read

The following code selects a string with two delimiters from the predefined list stored in `delimiter-strings`.  The first delimiter being the opening bracketing mark, the second delimiter being the closing bracketing mark.

I want to adopt the function to accept the pre-defined list in `delimiter-strings`, but also let users input their preferred delimiters (e.g. `"(]"`, `"(}"`, ...).  In case users input just one or more than two characters, I can count each of them.

```lisp
    (defcustom delimiter-strings '("()" "[]" "{}")
      "Two-character strings of open and close delimiters."
      :type '(repeat string)
      :group 'convenience)

    (defun echo-delimiter-chars (string start end)
      "Enter a 2-char string of delimiters, see what they are, return them."
      (interactive (list (completing-read "Delimiter pair: " delimiter-strings nil t)
                         (region-beginning)
                         (region-end)))
      (let ((open   (aref string 0))
            (close  (aref string 1)))
        (message "Delimiters you've chosen: `%c' and `%c'" open close)
        (list open close)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this instead of the `completing-read` call you show:

```lisp
(completing-read "Delimiter pair: " delimiter-strings)
```

That doesn't require the user input to match one of the `delimiter-strings`.  See what `C-h f completing-read` tells you about optional arg `REQUIRE-MATCH`.

---

But then you probably want to put that call in a `while` loop, testing whether what the user input is a string of length 2.  Or else just use the first two chars of the string input.  Or else use its first and last chars.  And at least test that the string is at least 2 chars.  Etc.

IOW, you need to actually define the behavior you're looking for.  Specify the behavior first, then implement it.

Comment: I could accept a sequence of characters, and count for each character.

Comment: Please don't use comments to respecify or evolve your question. Try to specify your question clearly from the beginning. This isn't a discussion forum. Comments are not searchable, and they can be deleted at any time. Questions and answers need to stand on their own.

Comment: Ok.  How can I check for two elements?  Would the check go in the `let*` part ?

Comment: No. What I suggested was replacing the call to `completing-read` in the `interactive` spec with a `while` look that keeps calling `completing-read` until what was input is a string of (at least two chars). IOW, test the result of `completing-read` till it's OK to use.

Comment: I would then need to test whether what the user input is a string of length 2, as you pointed out to me.  Have now set a variable `rqmatch` that sets the `REQUIRE-MATCH` for built-in function `completing-read`.